# WAMP : Forbidden Errors

Tags: php, html, wamp

I am a newbie to wamp , php and html , please excuse this primitive question.
but i am having lot of trouble with WAMP lately.

When i click submit button on the form , it gives me Forbidden You don't have permission to access

> /myproj/< on this server.

I am trying to create a simple form wtih drop down menu taking inputs.

please find my code below :

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <div align="center">
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
    Select a Template <br>
     <select name="template" id="rawquery">
      <option>Select</option>
      <option value="Alpha query">Alpha</option>
      <option value="Betaquery">Beta</option>
       <option value="Gamma query">Gamma</option>
       <option value="Epsilon query">Epsilon</option>
       </select>
       <br> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
        <br><br>
         </form>
        <?php echo $_POST("rawquery") ; ?>

        Raw Qyery :  <br><textarea name="raw" rows="10" cols="50" id="Raw">The Raw                 template as selected from the menu</textarea>
        <br><br>

      please input the values given below : 

      </body>
      </html>
```

I have tried changing :

`"<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"` 
to  `"<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>"`

with no luck the apache errors logs show the following :

> [Mon Nov 19 18:40:18 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (20024)The given
>   path        is misformatted or contained invalid characters: Cannot
>   map POST /myproj/%3C?php%20echo%20$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?%3E HTTP/1.1
>   to file, referer: http://localhost/myproj/Form.html

Any help will is appreciated please .
thanks in advance .!

the Source code on the server's page looks like this :

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <div align="center">
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
    Select a Template <br>
    <select name="template" id="rawquery">
    <option>Select</option>
    <option value="Alpha query">Alpha</option>
    <option value="Betaquery">Beta</option>
    <option value="Gamma query">Gamma</option>
    <option value="Epsilon query">Epsilon</option>
    </select>
     <br> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
     <br><br>
    </form>
     Raw Qyery :  <br><textarea name="raw" rows="10" cols="50" id="Raw">The Raw template as selected from the menu</textarea>
    <br><br>

please input the values given below : 

 </body> </html>
```

I have not added any PHP code as of yet , i have tried with that it doesnt work 
i can not even echo template ..

Comment: i have tired chaning  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; to "<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>" but it doesnt work

Comment: Are you sure your file is run by PHP? Because it looks like it is not. Please check the page's HTML code (when accessed through your web server) if the PHP tags are gone and replaced by actual values.

Comment: Don't forget to use isset(): `if(isset($_POST("rawquery")){ echo $_POST("rawquery");}`

Comment: @Cartsem i have added the source code of the web page on the question ..even while using any php code .its doesnt work i cannot even echo template in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a few mistakes but the major was the your select had the wrong name. When you POST something it takes the "name" attribute and not the "id". The second mistake was you used parenthesis instead of square brackets at the `$_POST`. Also your file that runs that has to have a `.PHP` extension. With the following changes (for me at least) it works fine. Try it and let me know! :)

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div align = "center">
            <form method = "post" action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                Select a Template<br />
                    <select name = "template" id = "rawquery">
                        <option>Select</option>
                        <option value = "Alpha query">Alpha</option>
                        <option value = "Betaquery">Beta</option>
                        <option value = "Gamma query">Gamma</option>
                        <option value = "Epsilon query">Epsilon</option>
                    </select>
                <br /> 
                <input type = "submit" name = "submit"><br /><br />
            </form>
            <?php if (isset($_POST["template"])) echo $_POST["template"]; ?> Raw Qyery:  <br />
            <textarea name = "raw" rows = "10" cols = "50" id = "Raw">The Raw template as selected from the menu</textarea>
            <br /><br />
            please input the values given below : 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: HI Jonur , thanks for the response it works for me as well now .however can you please explain what do you mean by "ou had a few mistakes but the major was the your select had the wrong name. When you POST something it takes the "name" attribute and not the "id". " i am new to PHP please excuse the inconvience.

Comment: Most were HTML. Please advise w3schools and you will see that must always close your tags. In your initial example, you begin with a `<div align = "center">` which never closes. The PHP would work still, but your presentation would be broken. Also ALWAYS close `<br />` tags like this instead of `<br>`. Finally, the best way to handle `$_POST` with an `echo` is the `isset()` function to avoid warnings.

If you didn't understand what I said regarding the attributes, then you need to study forms. `POST` takes and submits fields by `name`. So you need to `$_POST` with the field's name.

Comment: Okay ..okay i will study about forms from w3schools and get the details . i really appreciate your help thanks a lot